TexMaker Messages / Log Window disable
I am looking for a way to permanently disable the Messages / Log window in TexMaker.  Even if I have it unchecked from View menu, it still popsup with details. I need that popup to not happen anymore. Is there a .ini file that I can make that window hide=true ?
Thanks
I tried to search for the config file and I found it in AppData but there is no Message / Log to switch true of false.
